# Vega / Kibana Custom Visualization with multiple X axis parameters

Tags: kibana, vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to archieve something like this :
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OROby.png), using kibana and/or Vega/Vega-lite.

The csv file I used to add the index to kibana was:

```
student1,90,80,85,95
student2,50,60,55,100
student3,40,70,50,60
```

At the moment I have this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "data": {
    "url": {
      %context%: true,
      "index":"grades",
      "body":{
          "size":5
          "_source":["StudentName","test1","test2","test3","test4"]
        }
      },
      "format":{"property":"hits.hits"}
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "_source.test1", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "_source.StudentName", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

So my problem is trying to archieve what is on the picture. I know the "encoding" section of my Vega code isn't correct but I'm having problem finding a way of having multiple parameters in X-axis.

I think this : [vega example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/line-chart/)
would do the trick if i managed to replace the hardcoded values in data with the data from the kibana index. Is there any way I can use the "_source.fields" inside the "values" or is any option in encoding that I can use in order to archieve my result?

Thanks in advance.

Note: My end result most likely only have 1 student. But I want that the visualization to be updated in real-time, therefore the need to use the field.

Comment: think of your data differently, change the data so it can be provided to vega-lite and do what you are looking to do.  The name of the test or assignment is just another data point.  Your data columns could be: name, assignment_name, grade.  Then name and assignment name could be your x and y.

Answer (score 2):

You posed your question here and answers have been posted - https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1229#issuecomment-379593878